# How to restore default constant value in Julia

Tags: variables, julia

According to [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/variables/), in Julia I can do the following:

```
julia> pi
π = 3.1415926535897...

julia> pi = 3
Warning: imported binding for pi overwritten in module Main
3
```

How can I resore `pi` back to it's proper value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the original under `Base.pi`:

```
julia> pi
π = 3.1415926535897...

julia> pi = 3
Warning: imported binding for pi overwritten in module Main
3

julia> Base.pi
π = 3.1415926535897...

julia> pi = Base.pi;

julia> pi
π = 3.1415926535897...

julia> cos(pi)
-1.0
```